# Process won't start in python

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to prototype a simple python script to learn how to use multiprocessing. I want to have a process in the background that will generate dummy data and put it into a queue while the user is still able to type in commands.

Here's my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import random
import os

global run

def waitForStart(q):
    global run
    print("(h for help)")
    while run == 0:
        response = input("Enter a command: \n")

        if response == "h":
            print("h - help\ns - select a profile\no - output a profile\nd - 
download a profile\nd - display selected profile\nr - run selected profile")

        if response == "r":
            run = 1
            beginInterface(q)
            print("r")

def generateData(q):
    data = random.randint(0,100)
    q.put(data)

def beginControl(q):
    print("bcontrol")
    while run == 1:
        generateData(q)
        displayData()
        adjustOutputs()
        logData()
    print("Finished Control")

def beginInterface(q):
    global run
    p.start()
    print("binterface")
    while run == 1:
        response = input("pause? (y/n)\n")
        print(p.is_alive())
        if response == 'y':
            run = 0

def displayData():
    print(q.get())

run = 0
q = Queue()
p = Process(target=beginControl , args=(q,))
waitForStart(q)
```

I'm confused because the is_alive call returns false even though p.start() is called a few lines prior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two processes the `run` in the 2nd on is `0` and never enters the loop. To communicate between your main process and the second one use a [Pipe or a Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Important note, if on Win do not forget to add:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

[See reason here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)

Another thing, you never pass the Queue to `displayData`, edit to:

```
def displayData(q):
    print(q.get())
```

Also, **I think what you really want is a Thread** as this code will put the Process in an infinite loop.

This is not exactly your code but it conveys the idea:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pipe
import random
import time


def waitForStart(q):
    global run
    print("(h for help)")
    while True:
        response = input("Enter a command: \n")

        if response == "h":
            print("h - help"
                  "s - select a profile"
                  "o - output a profile"
                  "d - download a profile"
                  "d - display selected profile"
                  "r - run selected profile")

        if response == "r":
            run = 1
            beginInterface()
            print("r")


def generateData(q):
    data = random.randint(0,100)
    q.put(data)


def beginControl(q):
    print("bcontrol")
    while q.empty():
        generateData(q)
        displayData(q)
        #adjustOutputs()
        #logData()
    print("Finished Control")


def beginInterface():
    p.start()
    print("binterface")
    while True:
        print(p.is_alive())
        time.sleep(1)
        q.put('DIE!')
        p.join()
        exit()


def displayData(q):
    data = q.get()
    if data != 'DIE!':
        print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    pip = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=beginControl, args=(q,))
    waitForStart(q)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a little bit fuzzy on pipes so I'll read into that topic. I'm trying to have the process run in a loop controlled by the user input. What I would like to do is have the process continually generating and printing data to the screen while the user is still able to type in commands. Eventually I want to scale this to some code connected to LabView where the background process will be logging data from sensors, and I need the user to still be able to control the program through a front-end.

Comment: @egemnay, As noted, what you need is a Thread, not a Process - https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading